# Start a javascript when AJAX receive post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am coding a javascript script that makes an AJAX Post request for a PHP page that contains another javascript, I need the PHP page script to run automatically after receiving the response from AJAX, however it is not working and I am not finding any solution that fits specifically within that need. Any idea how I can fix this?

page01.php

```
<div id="value"></div>
<script>
function myClick() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    success:function(data){
      $('#value').html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

script.php

```
<script>
window.onload = startVerify;
function startVerify(){
alert("OK");
}
</script>
```

I believe it does not work because `window.onload` does not apply as the window has already been loaded. But I don't know how to make the PHP page code run the script automatically after the post. The solution can be pure javascript or jquery.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you been monitoring the actions and results in the console and network tabs of the browser devtools? Also, if you are using jquery, why do `window.onload = startVerify;` instead of the jquery `$(function() { });`?

Comment: Just for clarification, you're trying to *create javascript code* on your webserver using PHP, send that code back to the client via an Ajax call, then run it on the client?

Comment: um call it when the code is run??? `success:function(data){ $('#value').html(data); startVerify(); },`

Comment: @epascarello works perfectly! Wow, I didn't know that was possible call a function as a sucessfull AJAX response, this resolve a lot of problems to me! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

call this method to load the script in success of your post:

```
    function addScript(source) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.src = source;
        if (document.head != null) {
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
```

where source is your path of script. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: huh? What does this do with the Ajax call?

Comment: In the success, you have to load a script. So you can define this method anywhere in your JS and then call this passing your script path. It will load your JS.